# How to make two columns same height - Zurb INK

Tags: css, zurb-ink

I have two columns, one have more content = is bigger, but I want that black one to be same height like that on the right.

[image]

There is workaround that you add div around table width height 100% and display: inline-block, but it is an ugly hack.

Anyone know solution?

```
<table class="body">
        <tr>
            <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>

            <table class="container">
              <tr>
                <td>

                <table class="row">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">

                      <table class="six columns" style="background-color: black; color: white;">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <center style="vertical-align: middle; color:white;">
                              TEXT
                            </center>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>

                    <td class="wrapper last">

                      <table class="six columns" style="background-color: lightgray; color: white;">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                            <center>
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                            </center>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>

              <!-- container end below -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS class is what you need.  If you are just wanting the tables to be the same height just set the height for them both as the same.  either in-line or in a much easier way to manage is as a class applied to them both as below.  I also added your in-line code as css as its a far better approach.

```
    <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.tableHeight{
  height: 500px;

}

#lefttable{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;"

}

#rightTable{
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: white;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<table class="body">
        <tr>
            <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>

            <table class="container">
              <tr>
                <td>

                <table class="row">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">

                      <table id="leftTable" class="six columns tableHeight">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <center style="vertical-align: middle; color:white;">
                              TEXT
                            </center>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>

                    <td class="wrapper last">

                      <table id="rightTable" class="six columns tableHeight">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                            <center>
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                                TEXT</br />
                            </center>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>

              <!-- container end below -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Its responsive so i think that I dont want set fixed height

Comment: But its still best and i think only answer, thank you :]